# Stop Automapper creating empty objects on virtual properties when mapping from DTO to Entity

Tags: c#, automapper

I've set up my Automapper config and it's fine when mapping from Entities onto Dtos. However, when I try to map from a Dto back to an Entity, it populates all the virtual properties of the Entity with empty data, causing new objects to be created.

Psuedocode which should demonstrate the problem:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }

    public virtual MyOtherEntity MyOtherEntity
}

public class MyEntityDto
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }

    public virtual MyOtherEntityDto MyOtherEntity
}

config.CreateMap<MyEntity, MyEntityDto>()
    .ForSourceMember(obs => obs.MyOtherEntity, dto => dto.DoNotValidate())
    .ReverseMap();


// using this to create an Entity creates an empty MyOtherEntity object on it
var entity = Mapper.Map<MyEntityDto, MyEntity>(myEntityDto);
_context.MyEntities.Add(entity);

// so this tries to create a new MyOtherEntity in the db
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I can get around this by creating the entity manually, but is there not a way to set up Automapper to leave these properties empty?

Comment: `configuration.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;`

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks - can you set that on individual mappings?

Comment: No, just globally or per profile.

Comment: But in 10.0 things changed: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/10.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#allownull-allows-you-to-override-per-member-allownulldestinationvalues-and-allownullcollections

Answer (score 1):

For ReverseMap() AutoMapper creates a reverse mapping configuration that includes **unflattening** which results with creating new object for virtual property.
You can remove the call to ReverseMap() and create two separate maps or, you can use Ignore.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html